# automated testing using script injection on the web

Tags: javascript, testing, automation, automated-tests

I'm looking for a way to automate some simple testing of a web application. "Clicking x causes y" sort of testing. I want to write tests that can be run in a variety of browsers. I was thinking writing an inject-able script (bookmarklet sort of thing) which invokes click events and tests that elements exists might be a good way to go.

Are there any inherent dangers to this approach or major issues? Are there better alternatives? I don't want to get too involved in creating this test (don't want to create a test server, or go through a lot of setup), I just want to automate some repetitive testing.

Answer (score 1):

As Diodeus said, [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) is probably the most popular browser automation library right now (I believe Facebook uses it). Other frameworks you may wish to investigate:

- [Watir](http://watir.com/)
- [Windmill](http://www.getwindmill.com/)
- [Sahi](http://sahi.co.in/w/)

In addition, you'll want to consider cross-browser testing when setting up an automated suite of tests. You can roll your own for this, or if you'd rather throw money at the problem, [BrowserStack](http://www.browserstack.com/automated-browser-testing-api) now offers an API that allows your tests to run on a range of browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium is pretty popular: http://seleniumhq.org/